# XPath retrieving two queries

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, xpath, html-parsing

I want to retrieve the 'Course Leader' name AND email address from this webpage:

http://www.westminster.ac.uk/schools/computing/undergraduate/computer-games-development/bsc-honours-computer-games-development .

How could this be achieved?

I have attempted to retrieve the first `<p>` after 'Course Content' but doesnt quite work ..

```
"//div[starts-with(@id,'content_div')]/h3[.='Course Content']/following-sibling::p[1]
```

Comment: What's the `h4` check for? And what *kind* of 'doesn't quite work'?

Comment: Was testing something. At present it gets the course leader name but not the email address. How can it retrieve both?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what xml / xpath code looks like in Objective C, but I suspect that you *are* already getting all the information you need, you just need to do a bit more to take it apart. The node your xpath retrieves looks like this (I have edited the content):

```
<p>Anastassia Angelopolou<br />
Email: <a href="mailto:agelopa@wmin.ac.uk.invalid">agelopa@wmin.ac.uk.invalid</a></p>
```

so if you just ask for the **text** of the `p` node, you just get the text `Anastassia Angelopolou`, the (first) inner text up to the first child node (the `<br />`). To get the email address, you can xpath from the `p` node you have to the `./a` child node and take either the text or the value of `@href`.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are not really unique identifying tags on either of the values you are looking for I would skip xpath and just create a dirty little hack.

```
// get the HTML code.
NSString * getURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.westminster.ac.uk/schools/computing/undergraduate/computer-games-development/bsc-honours-computer-games-development"];
NSData * htmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getURL]];
NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


//seperate the HTML code by the unique HTML line of "<h3>Course Leader</h3>"
NSArray *tempArray = [htmlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"<h3>Course Leader</h3>"];
NSString * tempString1 = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:1]description];

//get Name
NSArray * tempArray2 = [tempString1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"<br />"];

//set name
NSString * nameString = [[tempArray2 objectAtIndex:0]description];
//clean up name string
nameString = [nameString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
nameString = [nameString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];
nameString = [nameString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<p>" withString:@""];

//get Email 
NSArray * emailArray = [tempString1 componentsSeparatedByString:@">"];

//set email string
NSString * emailString = [[emailArray objectAtIndex:3]description];
//clean up email string
emailString = [emailString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</a" withString:@""];

NSLog(@"Results: Name = %@  Email = %@",nameString,emailString);
```